# Cannot Upload File Online due to Win.Trojan.Toa-5372190-0 FOUND

Tags: cloud, hosting

I got error while uploading file, It constantly says "The file you uploaded, assets.zip, contains a virus so the upload was canceled: Win.Trojan.Toa-5372190-0 FOUND" , I did checked my files with latest virus definitions, from the multiple virus scanners, and it says everything is clean, but why am i getting this error uploading online.

Comment: which server you are using??

Comment: I am using Apache Server. Using the Shared Hosting From the provider.

Answer (score 0):

We had a situation on a server yesterday which uses ClamAV where it quarantined many files with that same signature, "Win.Trojan.Toa-5372190-0".  We checked a few of them against Kaspersky and they were clean.  We released a few of them from quarantine today and re-scanned them using ClamAV and today they are clean.  So, I assume the nightly signature update from ClamAV removed the false-positive signatures.  I would suggest resubmitting the file to see if the situation has cleared up and/or contact the provider.